# terraform azure install extension via terraform or gitlab CI

Tags: postgresql, terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-azure, azure-postgresql

Azure postgre sql can be installed via terraform(git lab CI). But how to configure extension. At the moment we are doing this manually.
For instance, application teams that have functionality that needs encryption can enable pg_crypto by using the `CREATE EXTENSION` command.

Also how can we deploy the schema and other sql changes in the future via a `gitlab CI` devops pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, we need to install few extensions manually into the main GitLab Database

This could be the default to `gitlabhq_production`

```
pg_trgm -> 8.6 is Minimum GitLab version
btree_gist -> 13.1 is Minimum GitLab version
plpgsql -> 11.7 is Minimum GitLab version
```

Using the below documentation from official GitLab we can manage the extensions of Postgre SQL

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/install/postgresql_extensions.md